# exfat card became read-only after automounting with GNOME Disks, and I cannot change permission even as root after that

Tags: permissions, mount, 22.04, automount, exfat

I am running Ubuntu MATE 22.04 on a Chromebook. Due to the limited internal memory of a Chromebook, I am using a 128 GB USB drive for storage. This drive is formatted as exfat, so that it can be used in both Windows and GNU/Linux. I want to automount the disk, so that its permanent location would not change, and my Cloud Storage Client (Mega) would be able to access it witout manual intervention.

I opened `Mount options` for this Drive in GNOME Disks, and enabled `Mount at Startup`.

After doing this, I cannot edit files in the drive. The drive is mounted as `/mnt/MyDrive`.

I tried `sudo chown -R myusername:myusername /mnt/MyDrive`, but it did not work (despite using `sudo`, it says "Operation not permitted").

I tried logging as root with `su` and `chown -R myusername:myusername /mnt/Files`, but still it says "Operation not permitted").

How do I fix this? I want to automount the drive, but also want to have read-write access.

---

Note: If I don't automount the drive, I have full read-write access in it (without `sudo`). In the past, I have automounted `ext4` drives, and I could `chown` it with sudo without an issue. This issue is specific to `exfat` (and maybe `NTFS` as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is partly based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/956072/124466) answer, which is about manual, normal mounting (but not automounting) of NTFS/exfat drives.

---

1. Open the file `/etc/fstab` as root.

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

2. Comment out the line corresponding to your particular drive (the label of my drive is `MyDrive`), and add the line

```
/dev/disk/by-label/MyDrive /mnt/MyDrive auto rw,user,uid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

3. Reboot.

---

**Note**: The label of my USB drive is `MyDrive`. You will have to change accordingly. You can also mount using the UUID instead of the label. See the Ubuntu Community Help page of [fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) for more details.